# How to call a function after vue-lazyload finishes loading?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using this component: 
https://github.com/hilongjw/vue-lazyload

Given the below code how can I call the function callMe once the image (imgUrl) is loaded?

```
<template>
   <div class="hero-unit-bg" v-lazy:background-image="imgUrl" >
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueLazyload from 'vue-lazyload'

Vue.use(VueLazyload)

export default {
  name: 'HeroUnit',
  data () {
    return {
      imgUrl: 'img/hero-unit-bg.png' // String
    }
  },
    methods: {
   callMe: function (event) {
      alert('Done Lazy Loading Img')
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use `this.$LazyLoad.$on('loaded', callback)` inside the `mounted()` hook (see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55310319/6277151) to your other similar question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation it is [described](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-lazyload#event-hook):

Event Hook

```
vm.$Lazyload.$on(event, callback) vm.$Lazyload.$off(event, callback)  
vm.$Lazyload.$once(event, callback)
```

`$on` Listen for a custom events loading, loaded, error
`$once` Listen for a custom event, but only once. The listener will be removed once it triggers for the first time.
`$off` Remove event listener(s).

```
vm.$Lazyload.$on
```

Arguments:
*{string}* event
*{Function}* callback

**Example**

```
vm.$Lazyload.$on('loaded', function ({ bindType, el, naturalHeight, naturalWidth, $parent, src, loading, error }, formCache) {
  console.log(el, src)
})
```